# Storing Hashed string Ids

Tags: c++, hash

I'm trying to implement unique identifiers for game assets and objects for a game engine.  I'm basing my design off the ideas from Game Engine Architecture by Jason Gregory.

So far I have two functions, `int internString(const char *str)` and `int FNVHash(const char *str)`.

`internString` calls `FNVHash` which successfully produces a hash of the string. I then insert the hash, string pair into `static std::unordered_map<StringID, const char*> idMap`.

The problem I have with my current approach is that to my understanding I am performing two rounds of hashing:

1. The hash of the initial `const char *str` inside `FNVHash`.
2. The hash of the int returned by `FNVHash` in order to select the bucket in the `unordered_map`.

I'm aware that I could override the hash function used in the `unordered_map` to use my `FNVHash` function if I changed the return type to `size_t`.  The second option I have come across is creating a custom hash table class containing a large array and then using FNVHash_return_value % size_of_array to select a bucket.  This second option seems like it would lead to a large number of collisions unless I make the array very large, however I think this is what Game Engine Architecture is implying as it uses a `HashTable` class.

How can I store my hashed strings without redundant hashing and an increased number of collisions?  Thanks.

Comment: String hashes aren't unique, you'll always loose information you can't recover back to the original. Depends on the bitsize of the hash, and the algo how much information is lost, and how probable collisions are.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I'm not sure I follow your comment.  Would you be able to expand it at all?

Comment: What I wanted to say is: If I understand your quesiton correctly, what you're trying to do (_"internString calls FNVHash which successfully produces a hash of the string."_) might be unneccessary, and could lead to collisions. If easily possible, rather associate a  uuid with these strings. But taking a second look, it doesn't apply for your case. Just a fair and stable hash algo, which proides a good distibuiton is sufficient in your case.

Comment: _"I'm aware that I could override the hash function used in the unordered_map to use my FNVHash function"_ You can also define your own key type, and provide a specialization for [`std::hash<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). This would be seamless, without further mess.